# Lambda expression and Fluent Nhibernate

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, lambda

How should this implementation look like with fluent nhibernate 1.0 rtm

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> {
public IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork {
get { return ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IUnitOfWork>(); }
}
public ISession Session { get { return UnitOfWork.CurrentSession; } }
public T Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression) { }
}
```

Comment: Well I guess that fluent nhibernate does not support linq expressions?

Comment: What is that? A method on your domain object? If you want an answer you're going to have to supply some *context*.

Comment: Sorry, my bad! I have updated my code and my question is if it's possible to use Linq expressions or if I should take another approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgraded to a later version of FNH which seems to have support for linq expressions